# Why is time complexity of Dijkstras Algorithm O(V^2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, shortest-path, dijkstra

I just read the article about Dijkstras Algorithm in Wikipedia als it says that the time complexity is `O(V^2)`. 
My problem is that I cant explain this to myself.

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

The `O(V^2)` solution using an array is the same as the "regular" (priority queue) solution, but using an array with the open distances instead, and searching in it instead of doing a heap lookup.

```
open_nodes = [inf, inf, inf, ..., inf]
d = [inf, inf, inf, ..., inf]
open_nodes[source] = 0
while d[target] == inf:
  v = argmin(open_nodes)  // O(V)
  d[v] = open_nodes[v]
  for each u such that (v,u) is an edge:
    if d[u] != inf:
      // relaxation:
      open_nodes[u] = min(open_nodes[u], d[v] + w(v,u))
    // close v
  open_nodes[v] = inf
```

- The loop repeats itself atmost `|V|` times, since you close a node
  each iteration, and never reopen it.
- `argmin` is `O(|V|)`. This is basically finding minimum in unsorted array.
- relaxation takes O(1), and repeats itself at most `O(|E|)` times, since you invoke it at most once for each outgoing edge.

This gives us total of `O(|V|^2 + |E|)`, but since `|E| <= |V|^2`, this is just `O(|V|^2)`